# Problem with Dockerfile causes "curl (56) Recv failure"

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker container from a nginx Dockerfile and am having problems. First I performed the following test:

```
# docker run --name test -p 8080:80 -d nginx:latest
# curl localhost:8080
```

This works without problems. Now when I am trying to build my dockerfile from a ready container my problems start. Below is my project:

**web/Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:latest
MAINTAINER braulio@braulioti.com.br

LABEL Description="Project Frontend"

EXPOSE 80

VOLUME ["/usr/share/nginx/html"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: web
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    container_name: "project_frontend"
    volumes:
      - /app/project_frontend:/usr/share/nginx/html
    command: /bin/bash
    tty: true
```

When I now try to use the "curl" command the result is as follows:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: You’re explicitly telling Docker to _not_ run nginx but to run a bash shell instead.

Comment: It was a copy/paste issue. Worked perfectly! Thanks @DavidMaze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @David, you are not starting nginx at all, as this line in docker-compose will override the CMD of Dockerfile.

```
command: /bin/bash
```

replace the command with

```
command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

or move this Dockerfile

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Or you the Nginx base image will take care of it if you did not mention at all.